# Predict the average temperature for next 30 years

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

Objective: I want to predict the average temperature for next 30 years.

Q1: What type of dataset is suitable for this (what columns should it contain)

Q2: What are the independent variables for average temperature?

Q3: Let's say I trained the model with 30% data. Does that mean predicted 30% is for next 30 years? Or is it present data? If not how do I predict the average temperature for next 30 years with the trained model?

Comment: If you are able to predict the average temperature for the next 30 years, you are Superman

Comment: I predict that the temperature is 70 Fahrenheit, so I am Superman, thanks! BTW I also predict it will be inaccurate

Comment: I think the problem needs more definition. What is average temperature - a certain city temperature at a certain time of day every day averaged over 30 years, average temperature in a select city over 24 hours, average in a country over 1 month at noon, 1 year, globally, etc. Are you including climate change? This is a hard problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have context where this problem originates from? You seem to be mixing up a few things.

Q1: depends on what dataset do you have available, or can you find? It can be just year and average temperature of the year, and then you'd apply a regression or ARIMA model.
But maybe you have average temperatures for various countries and regions, and then you could predict average temperatures per region.

Q2: again, depends on what dataset and columns you have. Typical independent variables are variables whose variation does not impact the temperature. Those typically have near 0 correlation with the temperature.

Q3: depending on the dataset, you probably should not use machine learning at all. Maybe regression/ARIMA is enough. And regression to predict values you should not do on partial data.

When you train a model with 30%, you use 70% for validation or scoring the model.

Your prediction could be just the extrapolation on the fitted curves on your data set.
You also have some information on the variations (R2), that can help give probability scores.
A typical outcome could be a 95% confidence interval that the temperature will be Tx +/- dTx.

Answer (score 1):

At a high level you need to find historical data matching what you need to forecast (average temperature) and any factors which influence it. So you need to be a domain expert, have access to one, or find data and do exploratory analysis to find for yourself what factors are important.

If you're using 30% to train the model, you're holding 70% back to test it. Since you're trying to forecast a timeseries you generally want to work out how the model scores in the future - this implies you train the model with the first 30% of your historical data and test it on the last 70% - which probably won't work well. In your case say you're training using yearly average temps for 100 years. It would mean you train on the first 30 years of data - from 70 years ago which doesn't seem like it would work. An alternative is blocked cross validation where you split the data into blocks which are long enough to minimise the effect of autocorrelation and then assign the blocks into test and train. I've found this method to be quite effective.